# Cannot install plugin cordova-sqlite-storage

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, cordova

I want to install cordova-sqlite-storage, but I get the error message bellow:

[image: error]

I have tried to unzip the `Cordova-sqlite-storage-master-public.zip` to the

> "D:\Project\hello\platforms\android\platform_www\plugins\cordova-sqlite-storage"

directory, but I'm not sure if this works or not because I cannot see the plugin in Eclipse after I have cleaned the project.

I'm new to Cordova. Can anyone help?

Comment: not sure if you need the android tag, as far as I can see this is about installation and configuration of eclipse with plugins

Comment: First: Googles SDK for android is Android Studio and not Eclipse. Second: Don't install plugin manually, read the documentation it explains how to do it.

Comment: Hi All, I have resolved it by installing the previous version of the sqlite plugin.   "cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage@0.7.12" .